# Tool That Convert mySQL Query To Zend FrameWork Query

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

Is there any Online Web Tool that Convert mySQL Query To Zend FrameWork Query.
that is i type mySql Query and the Tool Convert it to Zend FrameWork equivalent Query

Comment: Need a little more information - you can use regular SQL queries with `Zend_Db`, or build the query using `Zend_Db_Select`

Comment: I think your premiss is flawed. Zf generates SQL queries from php code. There is no special `Zend FrameWork equivalent Query`. You actually have multiple options on how you want to build your queries in ZF. If you really want to work in SQL, execute your SQL queries with Zend_Db_Statement and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a tool for this. Within Zend Framework's Zend_Db, component, you can do:

```
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
```

If `$sql` is a select, then you can retrieve the data with:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Alternatively, ZF is just a PHP framework, so there's nothing stopping you continuing to use [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) directly.

Comment: i know i can use mysql query,u know the difference b/w syntax of genral mysql query and zf query.zf query syntax is bit difficult so i need to convert mysql query to zf equailent query

Comment: The SQL string is identical if you use `$db->query()`. If you want to use the `Zend_Db_Select` object, then that is a different matter and you should post a separate question with an explicit SQL statement that you are trying to convert to `Zend_Db_Select`.