# how to convert mysql query to zend query?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to convert following sql query to zend query. How I can convert this mysql query into zend query with zend framework 2?

```
select * from user where BINARY username = "testUser";
```

Thanks

Comment: Possbile answer you were searching 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153740/tool-that-convert-mysql-query-to-zend-framework-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried this:

```
$select = $select->where('username' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("BINARY('testUser')"));
```

Comment: Thanks.Thanks a lot.Working successfully. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can write your query in Zend:

```
$select = $db->select()
             ->from('user')
             ->where('BINARY username = ?', "testUser");
```

Comment: Thanks. But this code it not working in zend framework 2 :( . This is ok with Zend framework 1.